# Overfull \hbox too wide in a table. This error is pushing the table off the template

Tags: tables, overfull

```
\begin{table*}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \caption{Performance comparison of NSL-KDD 5-Class}
\catcode`,=\active
\def,{\char`,\allowbreak}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrr} \hline
    Attack Class & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Accuracy(\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Precision(\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Recall(\%)} \\ \hline
          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{DBN} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{S-NDAE} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Opti\_NSDAE} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{DBN} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{S-NDAE} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Opti\_NSDAE} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{DBN} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{S-NDAE} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Opti\_NSDAE} \\ \hline
    DoS   & 87.96 & 94.58 & 99.87 & 100   & 100   & 100   & 87.96 & 94.58 & 99.87 \\
    Normal & 95.64 & 97.73 & 99.89 & 100   & 100   & 100   & 95.64 & 97.73 & 99.89 \\
    Probe & 72.97 & 94.67 & 99.85 & 100   & 100   & 100   & 72.97 & 94.67 & 99.85 \\
    R2L   & 0     & 3.82  & 10.67 & 0     & 100   & 100   & 0     & 3.82  & 10.67 \\
    U2R   & 0     & 2.7   & 9.82  & 0     & 100   & 100   & 0     & 2.7   & 9.82 \\
    Total & 80.58 & 85.42 & 99.87 & 88.1  & 100   & 100   & 80.58 & 85.42 & 99.87 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{table5.7}%
\end{table*}%
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome. Have you checked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options ?

Comment: It is indicating error message Overfull \hbox and the table has crossed the boundaries to the right.

Comment: Yes, that was clear. If you read the linked question/answer you can try several solutions, and if one of them that you think should work didn't, you can post a much more specific question here. Which one(s)did you try? (Ps: the overfull hbox is a warning, not an error...)